# What is the fallacy called when person starts to lose an argument they turn to humor and deflect the topic?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you are arguing and when you counter their point, and they have nothing left they start making fun of you. which is ad hominem attack. but it's also more specific. it's to use popular memes or move lines to give appearance of upper hand.

Comment: Deflection and comedic relief are sometimes good to ease tension in a heated argument. Red herrings aren't necessarily bad. If someone is making a slight against you, it's an ad hominem. Unless you're in a formal debate setting, pointing these out probably won't progress the conversation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Red_herring_fallacies

Comment: red herring is very close. thanks... so example. someone makes a invalid point, you point out. he/she responds with gif that is making funs of you and says "i kNow WoRds"

Comment: Ad hominem is a subset of red herring. **Fallacy of relevance** is another: https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Red_herring

Comment: It's the old *I-know-you-are-but-what-am-I?* tactic.

Comment: A.k.a. *retort*.

Comment: This is not about the English language. The answer would be the same in any language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [philosophy.se].

Comment: Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration ... wut? There is no option for Philosophy SE. (And I think it would just be a baseless retort.)

Comment: i'm looking for a word, best i can describe it is as a fallacy.